# Не правильный вывод title

Tags: php

Необходимо на определённых страницах устанавливать свой title, для этого я использую следующую конструкцию

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

    switch($url){
        case preg_match("/contacts/i", $url):
            echo '<title>Контакты</title>';
            break;
        case preg_match("/services/i", $url):
            echo "<title>service</title>";
            break;
        default:
            echo "<title>Главная</title>";
            echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/flexslider.css'>";
    }
```

Подскажите, почему она отрабатывает не верно?

Comment: preg_match возвращает 0/1, соответственно switch условие измените

Comment: Нужно switch заменить на `if/elseif/else`. От него тут всёравно толку нет.

Comment: В данном варианте, мне необходимо использовать только свитч. Что условие изменить это понятно, просто вопрос в том, на что его заменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить надо на `true`:

```
switch(true){
    case preg_match("/contacts/i", $url):
        echo '<title>Контакты</title>';
        break;
    case preg_match("/services/i", $url):
        echo "<title>service</title>";
        break;
    default:
        echo "<title>Главная</title>";
        echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/flexslider.css'>";
}
```